# link Timescale Database to Forge in real time

Tags: node.js, database, iot, autodesk-forge, timescaledb

I'm working with timescale database which is queried by Postgresql.

I'm looking for how I can stream in real time the data from my database to forge and establish the link between the database and forge using nodeJS. I need really your help.

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach with the best developer experience would be to go for a full-stack real-time framework such as [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/#!) or [FeathersJS](https://feathersjs.com/)

Check out this two samples to get your started:

- https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-meteor-sample
- https://github.com/dukedhx/viewer-iot-react-feathersjs